# How to change the center panel of a JField Border Layout

Tags: java, swing

This may seem like quite a simple issue, but I am baffled as to why my code is not working, and I would really appreciate if one of you lovely people would take a quick look at why that is please.

So I am trying to make a GUI for a project, and I have decided to go with a border layout. On the top is a `JPanel` with a logo and title that will stay the same. on the left is a `JPanel` with multiple buttons that potentially will change colour. Finally in the centre is where the magic happens. I have thus far managed to create a login screen which is working, and I am granted access, however when it tries to take me to the home screen nothing happens. 
[image]
[image]

What should happen (according to the logic I have applied) is that the `JPanel` in the centre should become blank, however as you can tell that is not happening. The logic behind the code is I have created two `JPanels`, one for the login and one for the home screen. I have a global variable `state`, and if the password is correct, then `state` becomes 1 and the code is recalled. In the code there is a switch-case statement which says that if `state` is 1 then not to load in the login `JPanel` but rather the home screen one, however as you can tell this is not working.

Any help as to why this isn't working, or any ideas on another way of completing this which would work will be greatly appreciated thank you!

```
public class Border implements ActionListener{  
JFrame f = new JFrame();  
JButton loginButton, homeButton, starButton, elementButton, userButton, aboutButton, creditsButton, addUserButton;
JTextField usernameField, passwordField, addUsernameField, addPasswordField;
JSpinner addStateField;
int state;
String username;
Boolean success;

Border(){  
    JButton b2=new JButton("SOUTH");;  
    //JButton b3=new JButton("EAST");;  
    JButton b4=new JButton("WEST");;  
    JButton b5=new JButton("CENTER");;  
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    f.add(topBar(),BorderLayout.NORTH);  
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    f.add(b2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);  

    //f.add(b3,BorderLayout.EAST);  

    f.add(menuBar(state),BorderLayout.WEST);  
    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            f.add(loginCentre(),BorderLayout.CENTER); 
            break;
        case 1:
            f.add(homeScreenCenter(),BorderLayout.CENTER); 
            break;
        case 4:
            f.add(addUserCenter(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
            break;
    }

    f.setSize(1000,600);  
    f.setVisible(true);  
}  

public JPanel menuBar(int state){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    String[] options = {"Home", "Check Star", "Add Element", "Add User","About", "Credits"};

    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        JButton button = new JButton(options[i]);
        if (i == state - 1 && state != 0){
            button.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        } else {
            button.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }
        button.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                homeButton = new JButton();
                homeButton = button;
                homeButton.addActionListener(this);
                break;
            case 1:
                starButton = new JButton();
                starButton = button;
                starButton.addActionListener(this);
                break;
            case 2:
                elementButton = new JButton();
                elementButton = button;
                elementButton.addActionListener(this);
                break;
            case 3:
                userButton = new JButton();
                userButton = button;
                userButton.addActionListener(this);
                break;
            case 4:
                aboutButton = new JButton();
                aboutButton = button;
                aboutButton.addActionListener(this);
                break;
            case 5:
                creditsButton = new JButton();
                creditsButton = button;
                creditsButton.addActionListener(this);
                break;
        }
    }
    panel.add(homeButton);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,15)));
    panel.add(starButton);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,15)));
    panel.add(elementButton);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,15)));
    panel.add(userButton);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,15)));
    panel.add(aboutButton);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,15)));
    panel.add(creditsButton);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,15)));
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    return panel;
}
public JPanel topBar(){
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Resources\\logo.jpg"));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Star Explorer");
    title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    title.setFont(new Font("Castellar",Font.PLAIN, 18));
    panel.add(title);

    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500,0)));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setIcon(icon); 
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    panel.add(label);
    return panel;
}
public JPanel loginCentre(){
    JLabel name = new JLabel("Username:");
    usernameField = new JTextField("username");
    JLabel pass = new JLabel("Password:");
    passwordField = new JTextField("password");
    loginButton = new JButton("login");
    JPanel screen = new JPanel();

    screen.setLayout(new BoxLayout(screen, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    screen.setBorder(new TitledBorder("login"));
    name.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    usernameField.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    pass.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    passwordField.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    loginButton.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    loginButton.addActionListener(this);

    screen.add(name);
    screen.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    screen.add(usernameField);
    screen.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    screen.add(pass);
    screen.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    screen.add(passwordField);
    screen.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    screen.add(loginButton);

    JPanel fin = new JPanel();
    fin.setSize(600, 400);
    //fin.setLayout(new BoxLayout(screen, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    fin.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,100)));
    fin.add(screen);

    return fin;
}
public JPanel addUserCenter(){
    JLabel name = new JLabel("Username:");
    addUsernameField = new JTextField("username");
    JLabel pass = new JLabel("Password:");
    addPasswordField = new JTextField("password");
    JLabel st = new JLabel("State:");
    SpinnerModel spinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,1,1);
    addStateField = new JSpinner(spinnerModel);
    addUserButton = new JButton("login");
    JPanel screen = new JPanel();

    screen.setLayout(new BoxLayout(screen, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    screen.setBorder(new TitledBorder("login"));
    name.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    addUsernameField.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    pass.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    addPasswordField.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    addUserButton.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    addUserButton.addActionListener(this);

    screen.add(name);
    screen.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    screen.add(addUsernameField);
    screen.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    screen.add(pass);
    screen.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    screen.add(addPasswordField);       
    screen.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    screen.add(addStateField);
    screen.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    screen.add(addUserButton);

    JPanel fin = new JPanel();
    fin.setSize(600, 400);
    //fin.setLayout(new BoxLayout(screen, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    fin.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,100)));
    fin.add(screen);

    return fin;
}
public JPanel homeScreenCenter(){
    JPanel fin = new JPanel();
    fin.setSize(600, 400);
    fin.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,100)));
    return fin;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    LoginDetails login = new LoginDetails();
    if (e.getSource() == loginButton){
        System.out.println(usernameField.getText());
        if (usernameField.getText() == "" || passwordField.getText() == ""){
            return;
        } else if (login.login(usernameField.getText(), passwordField.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ACCESS GRANTED!");
            username = usernameField.getText();
            success = true;
            state = 1;
            f.setVisible(false);
            Border.run();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ACCESS DENIED!", "WRONG PASSWORD", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == userButton && success){
        if (login.addToFilePermission(username)){
            state = 4;
            f.setVisible(false);
            Border.run();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ACCESS DENIED!", "INVALID PERMISSIONS", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == addUserButton && addUsernameField.getText() != "" && addPasswordField.getText() != ""){
        User u = new User(addUsernameField.getText(), addPasswordField.getText(),(int) addStateField.getValue());
        login.addToFile(u);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {  
    new Border();  
}
public static void run() {  
    new Border();  
}
```

Thank you! 
- Sam

Something quick to add, the only button on the left which is implemented is the addUser button, and that does not work either:
[image]
So if anyone knows why this is the case, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). It'd be more useful than posting 3 screen shots..

Comment: @AndrewThompson the problem is I am not to sure where the problem actually occurs in the code.

Comment: That's part of what creating an SSCCE / MCVE is is **intended to find out,** as explained in the SSCCE document! Given you've obviously not read it, down voting based on 'lack of research'. Follow links offered, and ***read the content carefully.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit of code that is run when the user's login is accepted will just make a new instance of `Border` who's `state` is by default 0:

```
state = 1;
f.setVisible(false);
Border.run();
```

`run()`:

```
public static void run() {  
    new Border();  
}
```

So what your really doing is changing the `state` of the `JFrame` that you make invisible (if you are done using a `JFrame` you probably want to call the `dispose()` method). So instead change the state of the `Border` instance made from `run()`

Also on a side note it may be worth checking out the [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for managing multiple `JPanel`s.

Comment: Thank you! I took your advice and I have gone with a Card Layout and that has made it much easier! Sorry for causing you trouble, thank you!